# How can I view the differences between an Android custom ROM and the official Android source?

Tags: android, git, diff, cyanogenmod

Having recently acquired an Android device, I started playing around with building a custom ROM image. I downloaded a version of CyanogenMod 7.2 ported for my device and built it successfully.

Since this is a port to my device, I'd be interested in comparing this ported code to the CM7.2 tree to see what kinds of changes went into making the port (since the xml file points to a bunch of different disparate git repos for various components, I'm not sure how I'd go about this). A similar question goes for trying to understand the differences between the CM7.2 port and the stock Android Source.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use any tool for comparing files. For instance, kdiff3. But it is better to compare using the functionality of git (or repo in case of Android).

Answer (score 0):

Add the "official" Android repository as a remote (I don't know the URL, so fill it yourself):

```
git remote add official url://to.official/android/repo
```

Then fetch from it:

```
git fetch official
```

You can then use all git tools (`git diff`, etc etc) to see the differences. Use `gitk` if you want a graphical view of the commit tree.

Comment: Do you know if I can download Google's XML file and add all of the official sub-repositories using the 'repo' tool. I'd do what you suggested but there's like 25 different git repos that the repo tool pulls in ...